# How to change the default value of property in base control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm going to build some wpf custom control for testing.

I have inherit the control from TextBox, and added some custom properties and event to control the behavious of this control.  However, I cannot find anyway to change the default value in Text property of the base TextBox.

Whenever I use the new control in my program, it will have the default value of the control name, and I need to clear it every time.

I have tried to clear the value in constructor of my custom control, but it doesn't work.

```
this.Text = "";
```

And I also tried to use the Style in Generic.xaml as below (the same way I used to change the foreground color), it doesn't work for Text property also.

```
<Style TargetType = "{x:Type local:NumericTextBox}"
  BasedOn = "{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property = "Text" Value = "" />
    <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value = "Blue"/>
</Style>
```

*(it works fine for Foreground color, but not work for Text)*

I have checked the definition of Text in TextBox, it should have default value of "", it seems that the default value was added somewhat after the constructor.

```
[DefaultValue("")]
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.Text)]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

May I know how I can change the default value of Text in my custom control?

Comment: The default value of the Text property should be an empty string in any case. Have you templated the control in any way? If it displays the actual name of your control, I suspect there is a wrong or missing template for the part that displays the text.

Comment: Really?  When you put a TextBox into the window, it should have the value of "TextBox" in Text.  This is the behavious of TextBox, my control just inherit this behavious.  Is your project a WPF Applicaiton or Windows Form Application?  The behavious of WPF control is different from Windows Form control.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? A TextBox without Text property set displays nothing: http://imgur.com/a/VOHtY

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but when I paste a TextBox to the windows, it will always have the Text value as the object type (i.e. TextBox).  If I create a custom object inherit from TextBox, it will have the value of my new object class.  You can try to create a custom object from TextBox, and put your object to a window, you can see the default value of Text.